# How to set up French Language for Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

Now that Google Assistant is available, is it possible to have the french language on a raspberry pie ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The google assistant is still not supporting French yet, until the time I am writing this post:

https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7394513?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

multi languages will be first supported in Pixel and then other devices like google home and then released in the assistant sdk, so i think you will have to wait for a while until you get in in the assistant sdk.

Comment: Actually, It's already avalible in France, Google Home works perfectly in french. That's why I'm asking if the api would work in french

Comment: Sorry for the wrong input then :) and thanks for the update